# java- who to add String to a linkdedList with the help of iterator

Tags: java

In the following code there is a method called `addNewItem` in the `ListItem` class which is responsible to get a linkedList and String from a user and then store them in a predefined linkedlist; in alphabetical order. In this class an iterator and comparison is defined to put the inserted values into the linkedList. Ihe problem is that when I run this application the inserted values don't show up in the linkedList. How do I assure the values will be added to the linkedList?

the class:

```
public  class ListItem {
    private String name;
    private LinkedList<String> content;
    private boolean forward = false;

public ListItem(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.content= new LinkedList();
}

public LinkedList<String> getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void moveForwards(LinkedList<String> linkedList){
    Iterator<String> i = linkedList.iterator();
    if(forward){
        if(i.hasNext()){
            i.next();
        }
    }else {
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }
        System.out.println("End of the list");
    }
}

public void moveBackwards(LinkedList<String> linkedList){
    ListIterator<String> i = linkedList.listIterator();
    if(!forward){
        if(i.hasPrevious()){
            i.previous();
        }
    }else {
        while (i.hasPrevious()){
            System.out.println(i.previous());
        }
        System.out.println("Top of the list");
    }
}

public void addNewItem(LinkedList<String> linkedList, String newItem){
    ListIterator<String> i = linkedList.listIterator();
    while (i.hasNext()){
        int comparison = i.next().compareTo(newItem);
        if(comparison == 0){
            System.out.println("This item is already exist");
        }else if(comparison > 0){
            i.previous();
            i.add(newItem);
        }else{
            i.add(newItem);
        }
    }
}
```

the main class:

```
public class Main {
    private static ListItem listItem = new ListItem("Jack");
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       listItem.addNewItem(listItem.getContent(),"Alex");
       listItem.addNewItem(listItem.getContent(),"Barney");
       listItem.moveForwards(listItem.getContent());
       listItem.

}
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete code for the main method of your Main class?

Answer (score 1):

In the `addNewItem()` method, the condition of the `while` statement is never `true` as the list is initially empty :

```
while (i.hasNext()) {
```

So the method invocation terminated without adding the item.

You should add the item after the `while` statement if required:

```
boolean mustAdd = false;
while (i.hasNext()){
    int comparison = i.next().compareTo(newItem);
    if(comparison == 0){
        System.out.println("This item is already exist");
    }else if(comparison > 0){
        i.previous();
        mustAdd = true;
    }else{
        mustAdd = true;
    }
}
if (mustAdd){ 
    i.add(newItem);
}
```